# Cross-reference named items in memoir

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir

I want to cite an item in an enumeration. I have a following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Peano Arithmetic, PA]
Peano Arithmetic is consists of following axioms:
\begin{enumerate}
\item[S1.] $\forall x : S(x) \neq 0$
\item[S2.] $\forall x : x=0\lor (\exists y: S(y) = x)$
\item[S3.] $\forall x \forall y : S(x)=S(y) \to x=y$
\item[A1.] $\forall x : x+0=0$
\item[A2.] $\forall x\forall y : x+S(y) = S(x+y)$
\item $\forall x : x\cdot 0 = 0$
\item[M2.] $\forall x \forall y: x\cdot S(y) = x\cdot y + x$
\item[O1.] $\forall x\forall y x\le y \leftrightarrow \exists z : y=x+z$
\item[Ind.] \label{induction} For any property $P(n)$, if $P(0)$ and $\forall n : P(n)\to P(S(n))$ holds then $\forall n P(n)$ also holds. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
 However the word \emph{property} in the axiom \ref{induction} is ambiguous.
\end{document}
```

The result I want to get is

> (...)
>
> However the word *property* in the axiom **Ind.** is ambiguous.

But it doesn't work. The situation doesn't change even if I change `enumerate` to `itemize` or `description`.

I guess that named labels are not an object can be labeled (Because my trials suggest the label refers the nearest unnamed label or the `\definition` environment.)

Is there any elegant way to help it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please edit this into a compilable example. When you override items like this you cannot refer to them, special methods (manually setting `\@currentlabel`) are needed. There are other questions about this on the site

Comment: Still not a compilable document. Please remember to test your mwe before posting.

Comment: @daleif I have two separate code (on the question and on my computer) so I couldn't find the problem. I guess it is compilable now.

Comment: It is, do you know the difference between `\ref` and `\cite`? Because `\cite` has nothing to do with `\label`. I'll post a possible solution in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed a lot of stuff that it not really relevant to the problem presented here.

There are two issues: (1) `\item[...]` is not referable, since you are manually setting the items, you might as well use `itemize` here, (2) when you have added a `\label`, to retrieve the data you need to use `\ref` not `\cite` (that is something completely different, a citation)

In this case we use a personal `\item` command that also sets the macro that `\label` gets its information from. Note that if you use `hyperref` in your *real* document, you need to use `\item[#1]\phantomsection\@currentlabel{#1}` in the definition of `\myitem`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{%
  \item[#1]\def\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Peano Arithmetic, PA]
Peano Arithmetic is consists of following axioms:
\begin{enumerate}
\myitem[S1.] $\forall x : S(x) \neq 0$
\myitem[S2.] $\forall x : x=0\lor (\exists y: S(y) = x)$
\myitem[S3.] $\forall x \forall y : S(x)=S(y) \to x=y$
\myitem[A1.] $\forall x : x+0=0$
\myitem[A2.] $\forall x\forall y : x+S(y) = S(x+y)$
\myitem[M1.] $\forall x : x\cdot 0 = 0$
\myitem[M2.] $\forall x \forall y: x\cdot S(y) = x\cdot y + x$
\myitem[O1.] $\forall x\forall y x\le y \leftrightarrow \exists z : y=x+z$
\myitem[Ind.] For any property $P(n)$, if $P(0)$ and $\forall n : P(n)\to P(S(n))$ holds then $\forall n P(n)$ also holds. \label{induction} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
However the word \emph{property} in the axiom \ref{induction} is ambiguous.
\end{document}
```

Comment: While the `%` characters I added are not strictly necessary here, it's better to have them, in order not to mislead beginners.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to define a new environment for this, modeled on the `description` environment as defined in `memoir`, but with the addition of a proper definition for `\@currentlabel`. Some juggling is necessary to get the definition in the right place.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{labeldesc}
 {%
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\z@
    \itemindent-\leftmargin
    \let\makelabel\labeldesclabel
  }%
 }
 {\endlist}
\newcommand*{\labeldesclabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep
  \normalfont\bfseries #1.%
  \gdef\labeldesc@label{#1}%
  \aftergroup\let\aftergroup\@currentlabel\aftergroup\labeldesc@label
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Peano Arithmetic, PA]
Peano Arithmetic consists of the following axioms:
\begin{labeldesc}
\item[S1] $\forall x : S(x) \neq 0$
\item[S2] $\forall x : x=0\lor (\exists y: S(y) = x)$
\item[S3] $\forall x \forall y : S(x)=S(y) \to x=y$
\item[A1] $\forall x : x+0=0$
\item[A2] $\forall x\forall y : x+S(y) = S(x+y)$
\item[M1] $\forall x : x\cdot 0 = 0$
\item[M2] $\forall x \forall y: x\cdot S(y) = x\cdot y + x$
\item[O1] $\forall x\forall y x\le y \leftrightarrow \exists z : y=x+z$
\item[Ind]\label{induction}
   For any property $P(n)$, if $P(0)$ and $\forall n : P(n)\to P(S(n))$
   holds, then $\forall n P(n)$ also holds.
\end{labeldesc}
\end{definition}
However the word \emph{property} in the axiom \ref{induction} is ambiguous.
\end{document}
```

[image]